# converting Promise to async await syntax problem

Tags: javascript

I want to convert promise in to async await but I cannot find the right syntax for the function that reads the data from the response

```js
export async function getDataFromServer(id) {
    try {

        const resp = await fetch('/dataget', {
            credentials: "same-origin",
            mode: "same-origin",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: `${id}`
        })

        const data = await resp.json()

        const handel = await function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            // render function 
            renderDataFromServer(data)
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (err === "server") return
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're facing?

Comment: what does `renderDataFromServer()` do?

Comment: Why would it run? `handel` is never called. I'm not sure what the point of `const handel = await function (data) {` is. I'd just remove that line.

Comment: renderDataFromServer (data)  don't run neither the console log the function after await doesn't get run also I cannot use arrow function

Comment: `await function(){`…`}` doesn’t make sense. A function expression doesn’t need awaiting. What are you expecting this to do?

Comment: it works but looks awkward  why I cannot wrap all of this in a function ? const handle = await
            console.log(data)
        renderDataFromServer(data)
        sumAllTotals()
 }

Comment: If you wanted to run renderDataFromServer() after data from resp.json() returns, you could call it directly under the await call
```const data = await resp.json();

renderDataFromServer(data)```

Comment: thanks Sebastian for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the unnecessary function declaration it should work:

```js
export async function getDataFromServer(id) {
    try {

        const resp = await fetch('/dataget', {
            credentials: "same-origin",
            mode: "same-origin",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: `${id}`
        })

        const data = await resp.json();

        console.log(data);
        // render function 
        return renderDataFromServer(data);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err === "server") return
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```